# Why is ggplotly's argument tooltip not ordering?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, ggplotly

The tooltip argument is a vector specifying which aesthetic mappings to display in the tooltip, and it was supposed to display and order the variables in the same way you wrote them on your code, but it doesn't, for me at least.

I've seen the same problem on the github's plotly issues page:

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/849

But it wasn't solved yet.

```r
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("y", "colour", "x"))
```

The order appeared on the tooltip is ("x","y","colour")
and not the one on the code ("y","colour","x")

Comment: If it is a known issue on github not sure I can offer a solution, but a workaround is to define a 'text' aesthetic i.e. `ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, text = paste(Sepal.Length, Species, Petal.Width))) ` then call `ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")`.  Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks @Dean ! It didn't occour to me to do that way, it is a workaround but it works haha.

Comment: that's great @Gustavo Utpott. Feel free to upvote if you found it useful, hopefully others may also benefit.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the reputation needed, this is my first question lol.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone else comes across this like I did. Have you tried this masking method with tooltip?

```
#ordering
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, 
text = paste("y: ",y,"</br>colour: ",colour,"</br>x: ",x)) ) +
geom_point()

#mask everything else and only show what's in "text" variable
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

Comment: Yes. I ended up doing just like Dean said on the comments, which is pretty much just like you did. Except that your code didn't work for me. There is no object "y" or "colour" or "x", but I think that if you refer to their real names on the dataset, it works.
``text = paste("y: ",Sepal.Length,"</br>colour: ",Species,"</br>x: ",Petal.Width))``